# Debug iPad memory issues via Mac

Tags: ipad, debugging, safari, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

We have a website which crashes the iPad.  On PC dekstops we've managed to lower the memory footprint by alot, and thought this would fix the  iPad crash issue.  It does not.
We have the iPad now connected to a Mac and are using Safari Web Inspector to debug it.
However, I do not see any option to view the ipad's memory use, or the size of the javascript objects.  Is there a good site to go to to learn more about how to use this technique?
Note that it's not a dev Mac with XTools, just someone's personal MacBook.
We really want to just detemine if the error is something otehr than memory usage.